# Read a large binary file(5GB) into a byte array in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, c#-3.0

I have a recording file (Binary file) more than 5 GB, i have to read that file and filter out the data needed to be send to server.

Problem is byte[] array supports till 2GB of file data . so just need help if someone had already dealt with this type of situation.

```
using (FileStream str = File.OpenRead(textBox2.Text))
{
       int itemSectionStart = 0x00000000;
       BinaryReader breader = new BinaryReader(str);
       breader.BaseStream.Position = itemSectionStart;
       int length = (int)breader.BaseStream.Length;
       byte[] itemSection = breader.ReadBytes(length );  //first frame data
}
```

issues:

```
1: Length is crossing the range of integer.
2: tried using long and unint but byte[] only supports integer
```

Edit.

Another approach i want to give try, Read data on frame buffer basis, suppose my frame buffer size is 24000 . so byte array store that many frames data and then process the frame data and then flush out the byte array and store another 24000 frame data. till keep on going till end of binary file..

Comment: Do you REALLY need all the data in memory at once? Because it sounds like you should implement a streamed approach to filtering the data.

Comment: yes....as have to read a specific pattern in file and have to apply filtration on that

Comment: I suggest that you process the file bit-by-bit if possible, rather than reading the whole file into memory. e.g. read the first chunk, filter it and then send it to the server (or write to a temporary file) before reading and processing the next chunk. Depending on what sort of filtering you are doing you might need multiple passes. Can you can provide more detail on what filtering is needed?

Comment: And which version of .NET framework you use?

Comment: i am using c# 3.0 , IDE VS2008

Comment: If you cannot make your project target .NET 4.5 (and of course run on machine with .NET 4.5+ installed) then you are out of luck. Otherwise, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Evk Although that allows arrays to contain more than 2GB bytes, it does NOT allow them to contain more than 2GB of elements (since arrays use `int` to index them) - so this has no effect on the maximum size of a `byte` array.

Comment: @user5794230 Why do you think *"have to read a specific pattern in file"* can only be done with the whole data in memory?

Comment: @user5794230 I am sorry, I do not understand what you want. What's the pattern you are looking for into the 5GB? How does it start? How does it end? How does it look like? Edit your question with the answer. Give us some example so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See you can not read that much big file at once, so you have to either split the file in small portions and then process the file.

```
 OR
```

Read file using buffer concept and once you are done with that buffer data then flush out that buffer.

I faced the same issue, so i tried the buffer based approach and it worked for me.

```
         FileStream inputTempFile = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);
           Buffer_value = 1024;
            byte[] Array_buffer = new byte[Buffer_value];
            while ((bytesRead = inputTempFile.Read(Array_buffer, 0, Buffer_value)) > 0)
            {
               for (int z = 0; z < Array_buffer.Length; z = z + 4)
               {
                  string temp_id = BitConverter.ToString(Array_buffer, z, 4);
                  string[] temp_strArrayID = temp_id.Split(new char[] { '-' });
                  string temp_ArraydataID = temp_strArrayID[0] + temp_strArrayID[1] + temp_strArrayID[2] + temp_strArrayID[3];
               }
            }
```

this way you can process your data.

For my case i was trying to store buffer read data in to a List, it will work fine till 2GB data after that it will throw memory exception.

The approach i followed, read the data from buffer and apply needed filters and write filter data in to a text file and then process that file.

//text file approach

```
           FileStream inputTempFile = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);
           Buffer_value = 1024;
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Path, true);
            byte[] Array_buffer = new byte[Buffer_value];
            while ((bytesRead = inputTempFile.Read(Array_buffer, 0, Buffer_value)) > 0)
            {
               for (int z = 0; z < Array_buffer.Length; z = z + 4)
               {
                 string temp_id = BitConverter.ToString(Array_buffer, z, 4);
                 string[] temp_strArrayID = temp_id.Split(new char[] { '-' });
                 string temp_ArraydataID = temp_strArrayID[0] + temp_strArrayID[1] + temp_strArrayID[2] + temp_strArrayID[3];
                 if(temp_ArraydataID =="XYZ Condition")
                 { 
                     writer.WriteLine(temp_ArraydataID);
                 }
               }

            }
           writer.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments, I think you have to read your file with a stream. Here is how you can do this:

```
int nbRead = 0;
var step = 10000;
byte[] buffer = new byte[step];
do
{
    nbRead = breader.Read(buffer, 0, step);
    hugeArray.Add(buffer);

    foreach(var oneByte in hugeArray.SelectMany(part => part))
    {
        // Here you can read byte by byte this subpart
    }
}
while (nbRead > 0);
```

If I well understand your needs, you are looking for a specific pattern into your file?

I think you can do it by looking for the start of your pattern byte by byte. Once you find it, you can start reading the important bytes. If the whole important data is greater than 2GB, as said in the comments, you will have to send it to your server in several parts.

Comment: i want to store complete data in byte array later i want to do filtration in that save data

Comment: @user5794230 well... *you can't*; you'll either need multiple byte arrays, or you'll need to stream over the data. You *could* also consider a huge chunk of unmanaged memory, or memory-mapped-files, but... that seems overkill here

Comment: @user5794230 Yes I get it, but I think you cannot because of the byte[] size limitation. You really cannot do you filtration part by part? That's look like a great algorithm challenge to me :D. As Said Marc Gravell, you can also look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 but I never use it so I can't help with that.

Comment: @user5794230 take a look at my edit. Does this can help you? It's just an example of reading byte by byte the whole data without an array but I don't know if the enumeration will be possible with your 5GB

Comment: @user5794230 Well, this was predictable :D. Please update your question with your filtration needs. I am sure you can do it part by part.

Comment: ok ..can you guide me ..suppose i want to frame by frame ..suppose my frame count is 24000 ..so i will read first frame ..then flush byte array data and then store next 24000 frame and process data...

Comment: @user5794230 Can you update your question with your needs? It is hard to read and to understand in the comments

Comment: update question can you please help... thanks in advance